# Create a dataframe containing the common values with similar sign among 9 dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, structure

I have nine data frames that all look like this:

```
    genes           logFC          logCPM        LR      PValue       FDR
23  FBgn0000055 -2.113383612    11.43516597 61.92994771 3.56E-15    8.12E-13
24  FBgn0000056 -0.950546502    7.089238204 16.06598503 6.12E-05    0.002332708
32  FBgn0000078  1.672097516    6.673033374 12.75593019 0.000354882 0.009887474
48  FBgn0000120 -2.243940769    1.185135121 16.62535349 4.55E-05    0.00181842
60  FBgn0000163 -0.872044452    4.813914339 24.48115988 7.50E-07    4.74E-05
76  FBgn0000239 -0.632832794    4.982140895 11.06560977 0.000879437 0.019890048
81  FBgn0000250 -0.709753728    5.627110077 17.11194875 3.52E-05    0.001472743
109 FBgn0000339 -0.814764584    5.637488206 19.68485845 9.13E-06    0.000450154
161 FBgn0000520  1.376149072    1.750060478 13.0027154  0.00031104  0.008886751
172 FBgn0000551  3.178580922    0.84274958  10.53931688 0.001168616 0.02496201
191 FBgn0000592  1.856439203    3.514427841 26.28516158 2.95E-07    2.10E-05
213 FBgn0000721 -0.638335899    5.580271418 11.24152661 0.000799873 0.018399823
222 FBgn0001075 -1.422251524    3.627148494 29.26552057 6.31E-08    5.35E-06
```

I want to create a new data frame that consists of only those genes that are common in all 9 dataframes (the gene ID's that all 9 share in the "genes" column) AND have the same sign (negative or positive) in the "logFC" column universally in all 9. In other words, if data frames share a gene id but have a logFC of the opposite sign in some of them, I DO NOT want that included in the new dataframe of shared gene ID's. I hope this makes sense and any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: If you stacked them into a single data frame, this would be straightforward. Hard to explain the steps without a real example, though. With dplyr, something like `rbind_all(List_o_DFs) %>% group_by(gene) %>% filter(n() == 9 && n_distinct(sign(logFC)) == 1)` maybe.

Comment: You can try something like `library(plyr); joined_df <- join_all(list(df1,df2,df3), by=c('genes','logFC'), type='inner')`